# Java Replace a substring after a certain number of repeats of that substring

Tags: java, substring

I'm working on an assignment that asks you to write a method to replace a substring with a new substring, but only if the original substring is repeated within its string a given number of times, and only replace the substring at that repeat.
We are given:

```
public class Statement

{

private String remark;

public Statement (String a){ 
    remark = a; 
}

 /**Returns the index in the statement of the kth str;

 *returns -1 if kth time does not exist.

 *Precondition: str.length() > 0 and k > 0

*Postcondition: the current statement is not modified.

*/

public int locateKth (String str, int k)

{ /*implementation not shown*/ }

/**Modifies the current statement by replacing the kth time of str with newStr.

*If the kth time does not exist, the current statement is unchanged.

*Precondition: str.length() > 0 and k > 0

*/

public void changeKth (int k, String str, String newStr)
```

We are then asked to write the method changeKth, and are given examples of how it works:

```
  Statement ex1 = new Statement(“The cat in the hat knows a lot about 
  that.”)
    ex1.changeKth(1, “at”, “ow”);
    System.out.println(ex1);
```

Returns: The cow in the hat knows a lot about that.

I know I will have to index the k instance of str, but I am not sure where to go from there to replace only that instance of str. I've seen people replace only the first instance of a substring, but not ever only instances after that. How would I do that?

Comment: use a for loop, and rather than using String.replace, create a new string using substring and indexof

Comment: **AND** show some effort before posting questions

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)` method from the `String` class to find all the times `str` appears in the sentence; setting `fromIndex` to the index of the last time `str` showed up until you've gone through the whole sentence. Such as:

```
String sentence;
String str;
String newStr;
int k;

List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int lastIndex = 0;

//LOOP UNTIL WE'VE GONE THROUGH THE WHOLE SENTENCE
while(lastIndex < sentence.length){
    //GET THE FIRST PLACE WHERE str APPEARS AFTER THE LAST INDEX WE'VE ALREADY LOOKED AT
    int index = sentence.indexOf(str, lastIndex);
    //KEEP TRACK OF THE INDEXES str APPEARS AT IN THE SENTENCE
    indexes.add(index);
    //UPDATE THE LAST INDEX WE'VE LOOKED AT
    lastIndex = index;
}

//GET KTH INDEX
int kthIndex = indexes.get(k);

//GET THE SENTENCE BEFORE str APPEARS AT THE kthIndex
String result = sentence.substring(0, kthIndex)
//ADD newStr (REPLACE str WITH newStr)
result += newStr;
//ADD THE LAST PART OF THE SENTENCE AFTER str APPEARS AT THE kthIndex
result += sentence.substring(kthIndex + str.length, sentence.length);

//THIS IS THE RESULT
return result;
```